# How to load data in Python for which data is stored as a customized class

Tags: python

I have a question with loading data in Python.

Basically, I defined all Classes I need in a file called "utility.py". and I have one data file "result.data" which stores results in form of a specific class called "Solution" which is defined in "utility.py". What I want to do is to load "result.data" in another py. file (ex:new.py). From what I know, cPickle module is the one that can be used. So in new.py, I wrote "from utility import *", and "Sol=cPickle.load(open('Result.data'))". This works fine when I worked among windows based system. However, when I tried to load the result.data I generated in windows system to new.py file in linux or mac system, The error "ImportError: No module named utility" always occurs.

I'm a not a professional programmer, and I just start to code in python. Could you please give some guide on how to solve this problem?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems like a deployment issue, it's hard to tell why `new.py` cannot import `utility.py` without you outlining what code files are available where.

Comment: just a tip - the names `utility`, `result`, `solution` and `new` are very generic and do not describe what your code is doing. You should consider renaming them to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Check `sys.path`. Does it contain the location where utility.py is kept? Does it have current directory ( an empty string )?

That could be the issue.